# Get enum value as string

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
enum myEnum
{
    a = 0101,
    b = 2002,
    c = 0303
}
```

I try to get enum value with casting but the `0` at the begin of my enums was removed.

For example I tried this:

```
var val = (int)myEnum.a;
```

How can get enum value as string when we have `0` at the beginning of it?

Comment: How should the system know whether you want to have zero, one or more leading zeros? Did you know that `1` is the same as `01` and `001`? (So actually James Bond is not 007 but actually just 7).

Comment: Enum is an int, the value is saved as such and your formatting is removed, consider using a different structure to save your formatting if needed

Comment: Do you need 0101 as string or need "a" as output?

Answer (score 1):

You should rethink your design, but if you want to check your enum integers to a given string, you can use `.ToString("0000")` to get the string `"0101"` out of the integer `101`.

Answer (score 1):

If you always need a specific number of digits you could use string format to get the leading zeros:

```
var str = String.Format("{0:0000}", (int)myEnum.a);
```

Or, shorter:

```
var str = $"{(int) myEnum.a:D4}";
```

**Alternative:**

Use an attribute to add extra information to an enum

*Attribute:*

```
public class DescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public DescriptionAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

*Enum:*

```
enum myEnum
{
    [Description("0101")]
    a = 101,

    [Description("2002")]
    b = 2002,

    [Description("303")]
    c = 303
}
```

*Extension Method:*

```
public static string GetDescription(this myEnum e)
{
    var fieldInfo = e.GetType().GetField(e.ToString());
    var attribute = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
    return attribute.Name;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var name =  myEnum.a.GetDescription() //will return '0101'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, enums are integers, since as their name says, they are enumerations and an enumeration, they are numbers, so enum is integer.

Secondly, you must bear in mind that zero is a null value, since the system is a 01 or 001 like 1, since (basic mathematics) a zero to the left is worthless, so this code is incorrect.

```
enum myEnum
{
   a=0101,
   b=2002,
   c=0303,
}
```

The correct way is

```
enum myEnum
{
   a = 0,
   b = 1,
   c = 2
}
```

Where the zero is alone, so the system sees it as an index

Now with this, you should only use one of the conversion processes of C#

```
string strOne = ((myEnum)0).ToString();
string strTwo = ((myEnum)1).ToString();
string strThree = ((myEnum)2).ToString();
```

Read the MSDN reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration values are always integers. If you need to associate a string with an enumeration value, you can use a dictionary:

```
enum myEnum { a, b, c }

Dictionary<myEnum, string> lookup = new Dictionary
{
    { a, "0101" },
    { b, "2002" },
    { c, "0303" }
};
```

To get the string associated with a particular value just use this:

```
var s = lookup[myEnum.a];  // s = 0101
```

Another common way to handle this sort of problem is simply to use constants.

```
class MyConstants
{
    public const string a = "0101";
    public const string b = "2002";
    public const string c = "0303";
}

var s = MyConstants.a; // s = 0101
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using *formatting*: you want **4** digits and that's why you can put `d4` format string. In order to *hide* all these implmentation details (cast and formatting) let's write an *extension method*:

```
  enum myEnum {
    a = 0101,
    b = 2002,
    c = 0303
  }

  static class myEnumExtensions {
    public static string ToReport(this myEnum value) {
      return ((int)value).ToString("d4"); // 4 digits, i.e. "101" -> "0101"
    }
  }

  ...

  myEnum test = myEnum.a;

  Console.Write(test.ToReport());
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that the numbers in your enum always have a length of 4
you can use the following

```
var val = (int)myEnum.a).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')
```